# This application does not have the required permissions for this endpoint on account

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am using stripe implementation with Node JS by following [this API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/create?lang=node). I am able to create connect and account but I can't add **external** bank account for the connected stripe account. I am using Test account credentials.  Connected account `acct_1KCRy1PszwCMk9PS` is enabled. I can't add external account to the connected account from stripe console also. The error says,

> This application does not have the required permissions for this
> endpoint on account 'acct_1KCRy1PszwCMk9PS'.

**Code:**

```
  let accountNumber = '000999999991' //https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing
  let name = 'testanme'
  let object = "bank_account"
  let country = "US"
  let currency = "USD"
  let stripeAccountNumber = 'acct_1KCRy1PszwCMk9PS'

  await stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(
       stripeAccountNumber,
       {
         external_account: {
            object:object,
            country:country,
            currency: currency,
            account_holder_name:name,
            account_number:accountNumber
         },
       }
  ).then(

       function(result) {

            console.log(result)
       },

       function(err){

            console.log(err.message)
       }
  );
```

Could you please help me to find out what is the problem? Thanking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This account is likely Standard account, where the external accounts used for payouts are [managed by Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts#choosing-approach) and are not [controlled by your platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/platform-controls-for-standard-accounts).

If you want to have full control over an account experience, you might want to consider Custom accounts, where this is reversed and you are responsible for collecting external account details.

Answer (score 1):

Either you use Standard API secret key or else you can create Restricted keys with below permissions
[image]

helper url https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys

Comment: Thank you! This helped us out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it guys. I was using restricted test key and each key (product and restricted and any) has different api keys settings for different actions, the error message will tell you which api key action you must change from none to write. Where it says reveal your key U have three dots on the right and there U can edit api keys, I had to change three api keys because each were giving error until I changed all three to write mode.