# Stripe connected account with Restricted Keys is throwing permission error while attaching bank account with express connected account

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, strip

I'm trying to add a bank account (onboarded with `stripe.tokens.create()`) as an external account under a specific **express** connected account.

I generated a Restricted key which contains below list of permissions. (Ref taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70564587/this-application-does-not-have-the-required-permissions-for-this-endpoint-on-acc))
[image]

I'm using below code to attach the account as external account under that **express** account. The code looks like this.

```
await stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(
 acctId,
 {
   external_account: bTokId,
 }
);
```

yet this is the error what I'm getting in postman,

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "message": "This application does not have the required permissions for this endpoint on account 'acct_12345'."
}
```

and in logs, I can see its `oauth_not_supported` error, which is something like this.

```
rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
code: 'oauth_not_supported',
```

But while creating the test express account I allowed oauth as well.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Express users have access to their own Express Dashboard to manage their external account(s) -- you can't manage this as the platform via the API. If you want, you can pre-fill the external account when you actually create the Express account (but you can't update it after it has been created). Otherwise you use an Account Link to redirect the Connected Account user to their Dashboard for this update. Lastly, if you do want this level of control, you should use Custom accounts instead of Express.